# Zeppelin - Spark SQL failing to parse input 'IN' in query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am trying to run a query that uses Spark SQL from a Zeppelin Notebook that is connected to AWS Glue.

Spark Version : 2.2.1

```
%pyspark
query='''
SELECT POSITION('bar' IN 'foobarbar')
'''
tt = spark.sql(query)
```

This gives me following error :

```
ParseException: u"\nmismatched input 'IN' expecting {')', ',', 'OR', 'AND'}(line 2, pos 22)\n\n== SQL ==\n\nSELECT POSITION('bar' IN 'foobarbar')\n----------------------^^^\n"
```

[API Documents](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#position) for latest version of spark shows this query is correct. However there are no API docs for v2.2.1.

Can someone tell me if `position` is supported in older version and if yes then what is the correct syntax ?

Comment: Why not use `%sql` as the cell header?

Comment: Since I am trying to collect the output in a dataframe object that I can later use. Also using %sql > SELECT POSITION('bar' IN 'foobarbar')   , gives the same error.

Comment: Ah... So, I think that linked page is literally for the `spark-sql` CLI, not PySpark.

Comment: Yes. But the functions should work in Pyspark too.

Comment: Should ;) The alternative is the locate function https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.locate